# Evaluate $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin7t}{\sin t}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{\sin\frac{7x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} & \text{if }x\neq 0 \\ 7 & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$
then $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)dx$ has the value equal to

$$(A)\pi-1\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{4}{3}\hspace{1cm}(D)\pi-\frac{4}{3}$$

Write $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\frac{7x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}dx$ and let $\frac{x}{2}=t$ Then

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin7t}{\sin t}dx .$$

But now here i am stuck,do i have to expand $\sin 7x$ or there is some other way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $$I_m=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin mt}{\sin t}dt,$$

$$I_{n+2}-I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin(n+2)t-\sin nt}{\sin t}=\int_0^{\pi/4}2\cos(n+1)t\ dt$$

Comment: Using this method i am getting $I_7=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{3}$,but it is not in options,Is my answer correct anyways?@lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @user1442 You forgot a $2$ in doing substitution $t = x/2$.